# Change hamburger menu icon - Xamarin.Forms Android & UWP

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have seen some similar questions to this one for Android in Android studio or UWP only, but I'm building a Xamarin.Forms app for UWP and Android and I would like to change the hamburger icon to a custom one I've made. Here is what it currently looks like on Android:

[image: hamburger menu 1]

It looks similar on UWP, but here is basically what I'm going for:

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this on my master detail page? I was looking for some tag element I could use in the .xaml file maybe like this:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master hamburgerIcon="myHamburgerIcon.png">

</MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Or do I have to do platform specific code like a custom renderer for both UWP and Android? To be clear I'm asking how to change the icon for the 3 bars (hamburger icon), but if someone could include how to change the action bar background color as well that would be a bonus.

Comment: set the Icon property of the page that is being used for the Master

Comment: @Jason How and where? I tried adding this line `Icon="hmenu.png"` in the `<MasterDetailPage>` opening tag but it didn't do anything

Comment: if Menu.xaml is your Master, then in Menu.xaml

Comment: OK I tried it as stated above, didn't work.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I have not found a solution yet. I tried setting the Icon and IconImageSource attributes in multiple places but unfortunately no success yet.

Answer (score 2):

> Change hamburger menu icon - Xamarin.Forms Android & UWP

For UWP part, you could replace hamburg icon easily. Because in UWP platform, it was render with the [button](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/MasterDetailControlStyle.xaml#L18) with `PaneButton` style, And you could find it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/Resources.xaml#L87). Just copy it to UWP **App.xaml** file and replace the content property like the following.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="PaneButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE701;" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

For Android part, we need custom `MasterDetailPageRenderer` render like the following

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(IconNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace masterDe.Droid
{
    public class IconNavigationPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
    {
        public IconNavigationPageRenderer(Context context):base(context) { }
        private static Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar GetToolbar() => (CrossCurrentActivity.Current?.Activity as MainActivity)?.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);



        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
            var toolbar = GetToolbar();
            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < toolbar.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    var imageButton = toolbar.GetChildAt(i) as Android.Widget.ImageButton;



                    var drawerArrow = imageButton?.Drawable as DrawerArrowDrawable;
                    if (drawerArrow == null)
                        continue;


// replace default hamburg icon
                    imageButton.SetImageDrawable(Forms.Context.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.icon));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the Application Resources dictionary in my App,xaml file and tried this <Style x:Key="PaneButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="ImageSource" Value="hmenu.png" />
            </Style> But it didn't work. I have not tried the Android solution you suggested, it seems complicated. Though I will eventually try if I cannot find a simpler solution.

Comment: Please note we need place PaneButton style in uwp project `App.xaml`.